# Can I apply for visit visa in the UK while my settlement visa application is still pending for tribunal appeal?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

My settlement visa in the UK was refused recently and I'm now waiting for tribunal appeal. Can I apply for a visit visa in the UK now?

Comment: What was the reason for the refusal? And what is the purpose of your intended visit?

Comment: Whether allowed or not, it is _unwise_ to do so.

Comment: A very bad idea: there s a high probability that a visitor visa would be refused, another negative mark in your immigration record which can lead to long-term consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Your application for a settlement visa and appeal against its refusal say that you're very keen to live in the UK. I'm no expert but I'd be very surprised if they would accept a visitor visa application: they'll assume that you still want to live in the UK and will do so illegally if you're given a visa.